# Estimating the effective area and temperature coeffecient of a solar panel

Tags: solar-energy, photovoltaics, linear-systems

I have a bunch of solar panels, each one is connected to an inverter.
For each solar panel I have two sensors, a wind and a west sensor.
From every inverter, I collect the power output.

The readings are collected for every 5 minutes, and I have a dataset over 7 days.

I know that the power can be estimated using the equation:
$$\rho_A=irr_s*A_e*(1+\eta_T*(T_m-25°C))$$
where,

$\rho_A$ the expected poweroutput
$irr_s$ the solare irradiation on the PV-Panel
$A_e$ the effective are of the PV-Panel (a Product of the effective effeciency of the Panel and the actual area),
$\eta_T$ the Temperaturecoefficient of the Panel and
$T_m$ the Modul temperature

Here is what I did so far:
I only used the west sensor as I thought the wind sensor has little effect on the power output of a solar panel(common sense?). Then, I grouped the data by hour and then day, for example, for on the 22.12.2022 i got 24 readings, and so on. Now I calculated the two unknowns, $A_e$ and $\eta_T$. I plotted them on a graph, see below:
[[image: <span class=]$A_e$ and $\eta_T$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTAEG.png)

Do you think my approach is good? How else could one approach this problem? Thank you for your inputs in advance!

Comment: What are the inverter losses? And then how will you separate panel v inverter losses? Why not just connect calibrated rwsistors to each panel and measure current, voltage and insolation?

Comment: As for wind, that can help cooling and improve output - so more wind = higher output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the wind sensor. Basically, i forgot to mention but, I just have the data and cannot change the setup anymore.